# not displaying after clicking About page using <Link to='./about'>About</Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Navbar.js

```jsx
<nav className='navbar bg-primary'>
  <h1>
    <i className={icon} />
    {title}
  </h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

App.js

```
<Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
```

Expecting about page to load when I click on the link.

Comment: Can you show the context (chains of parent tags) of the Route? Also, is there any error?

Comment: try with this `<Route path='/about' element={<About />} />` and let me know your thoughts.